# Как получить данные в строку страницы index.php? при отправке формы с index.html?

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <center>
        <h1>Alladin</h1>   

        <?php
            echo " <h3>
            В одном персидском городе **$city** жил бедный портной [tailorName]. У него были жена и сын по имени [sonName]. Когда Аладдину исполнилось [age] лет, отец его сказал:
            —   Пусть мой [sonName] будет портным, как я,— и начал учить Аладдина своему ремеслу.
            </h3> ";
        ?>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: #offtop: "Правильно заданный вопрос - половина ответа".

Как я понял, у тебя на index.html есть форма, где прописан action="index.php", и тебе нужно при сабмите формы получить содержимое, которое ты показал нам (<center> </center>) и куда-то вывести.. то используй ajax запрос.

Comment: Здесь нужно вывести в тексте:

echo " 
В одном персидском городе [вывести содержимое] жил бедный портной [вывести содержимое]. У него были жена и сын по имени [вывести содержимое][вывести содержимое]. Когда Аладдину исполнилось [вывести содержимое] лет, отец его сказал:
— Пусть мой [вывести содержимое] будет портным, как я,— и начал учить Аладдина своему ремеслу.
";

а вариант echo $_POST['city'] не подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у тебя должна быть форма в index.html

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input name="tailorName">
<input name="sonName">
<input name="age">
<input name="city">
</form>
```

Далее в index.php

```
<?php
  echo "<h3>
  В одном персидском городе ". $_POST["city"]. " жил бедный портной " . $_POST["tailorName"] . ". У него были жена и сын по имени " . $_POST["sonName"] . ". Когда Аладдину исполнилось " . $_POST["age"] ." лет, отец его сказал:
  —   Пусть мой ".  $_POST["sonName"] ." будет портным, как я,— и начал учить Аладдина своему ремеслу.
  </h3> ";
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, работает. Не хватало $_POST["city"]

Answer (score 0):

У формы прописываем action="./index.php", у каждого поля в форме пропишите name=""
В php файле все данные будут отображены в $_POST, сделайте print_r($_POST) для наглядности

Comment: Пробую так, но возвращает ошибку:         <?php
            echo " <h3>
            В одном персидском городе" . echo $_POST['city'] . "жил бедный портной [tailorName]. У него были жена и сын по имени [sonName]. Когда Аладдину исполнилось [age] лет, отец его сказал:
            —   Пусть мой [sonName] будет портным, как я,— и начал учить Аладдина своему ремеслу.
            </h3> ";
        ?>